# Permutations of two sets with non repeating rotations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I'm not sure if this will make sense, I'm not incredibly math orientated but I need to solve a problem.

Given a piece, it can have a block, a dash or nothing. These blocks dashes or nothings can be at the north, east south and west. Only one of these 3 things can be at north and south etc.
SO I. E we cannot have two things at east like two blocks or one block one nothing.

I want to know how to find the number of permutations (combinations?) that can be created from this setup for a single piece.

However some of these permutations can be rotations of eachother. I. E if I have nothing everywhere but north had a block and nothing everywhere but east has a block. The east one is just the rotated version of the north.
I wish to discount these from the final result.

Can you give me hints on how this would be done?

Comment: If i understand well, in each position (N,S,E,W) on each piece there is one and only one symbol chosen in this family of three symbols :{block/dash/nothing} ?

Comment: You don't want rotations, but are you ok with symetry ?

Answer (score 1):

- Number of coins with four times the same symbol: $3$
- Number of coins with two symbols, one once and the other 3 times: $3*2=6$ (3 ways to choose the first symbol, two ways to choose the second)
- Number of coins with two symbols, both twice: $3*2=6$
  (3 ways to choose the symbol that doesn't appear, and two schemes: ABAB or AABB)
- Number of coins with the three symbols, the two identical ones side by side: $3*2=6$ (three ways to choose which one appears twice, and then it's either AABC or AACB)
- Number of coins with the three symbols, the two identical ones facing up: $3$ (since ABAC and ACAB are just the same coin after a rotation of 180°)

Total number of possible coins: $24$

*(assuming that two symetrical coins are considered different)*

Comment: OK. This is interesting. So I knew the answer was already 24 as it was given but I was interested how this value came about. Now I'm wondering how easy or hard this would be to programmatically compute and also create

Comment: I suppose my next question is how did you figure that out? Trial and error? Was there math behind it I don't know that could be learnt?